# Is the game Wakfu really fully coded in JAVA?

Tags: 2d, java, lwjgl

If so, this shows that you can develop **amazing** logic/graphic wise games with JAVA. I think this should be used as an example when people ask about games developed in java instead of just mincraft and runescape.

Comment: You seem to have a message hidden in a question. But it is not a very constructive question. See the [FAQ](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/626/is-how-was-entire-game-x-made-off-topic).

Comment: There seems to be a question hidden in the message...

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is some kind of weakly disguised advertising, but a quick googling says yes, Wakfu seems to be written in Java. But while it looks very nice, I don't see anything "amazing" with regard to Java or technology in general. I've only seen the trailer now and not played myself, but Minecraft seems to still be far more complex with regard to game logic - just think about the terrain generation alone. A crafting system, enemy AI, fluid spreading, day/night cycle, lighting, portals and all that won't create themselves either.

From a grahpic point of view, Minecraft doesn't have too much to show, but Wakfu seems to be made up of pretty drawn sprites and tiles, which has nothing to do with the programming language or even the engine, but more with the artists and their tools.

A game will look as good as the artwork, animations, shaders and stuff you put into it, and as long as we're not talking about really high end, GPU melting games like Crysis, I don't see why Java shouldn't be able to do it. It's the same misconception a lot of people have about specific engines: Unreal Engine 3 doesn't automatically make your game look good and a free engine doesn't automatically look bad.

Comment: http://www.wakfu.com/na/mmorpg/game/game-system 
I've never seen a game developed in java this polished. I have no idea how you are not amazed. Perhaps you should try the game. Even though I know little about programming yet something tells me that this game could get by far more complex than minecraft.

Comment: This seems more and more like advertising. Just because you haven't seen it doesn't mean that it doesn't exist or can't be done. Head over to [Armor Games](http://www.armorgames.com) or [Kongregate](http://www.kongregate.com) and you'll be amazed at the quality of some of the games there, even though it's mostly "just" Flash. And while it can be fun (no, I won't try the game), I see nothing special about planting and harvesting stuff, levelling up or professions. It has all been done before. Again, not saying the game is bad, but from a technological viewpoint nothing extraordinary.

Comment: lol why would I be advertising a game. "Just because you haven't seen it doesn't mean that it doesn't exist or can't be done." Wut? All I'm saying is that they've done something I've never seen before in JAVA and it amazed me.. We won't probably find many more projects being developed in JAVA that look as good. Doesn't that give some merit to the game itself and to the language?

Comment: I have seen many and many awesome games developed in flash... the point I'm trying to make is that this company developed something never seen before with JAVA and it deserves some merit and should inspire people making games in JAVA just like minecraft and runescape do. Please cut the advertising bs. I don't even play it anymore and I don't care if anyone wants to try it or not.

Comment: How should I know the reason why anyone advertises a game? Maybe an employee, maybe getting paid for it... All I'm saying is the whole "This game looks SO amazing and is so incredibly complex" with a link and "try the game" thrown in _reads_ like advertising. If that's really not the case, I'm sorry. But still, I think this game is just one of many, even if it's good. The sprites don't care if it's Java, Flash or C++ that draws them to screen and I still fail to see where the game is technologically more complex than other available Java games.

Comment: If you could only name me any MMORPG developed in JAVA that looks fun graphic/gameplay wise... > Minecraft/Runescape what else is there?

Comment: I don't usually research the language of games, but there is for example [Pirate Galaxy](http://pirategalaxy.com/). Then there's the [jMonkey engine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/) used for all kinds of stuff. Why the fixation on MMORPG anyway? [Blocks That Matter](http://www.swingswingsubmarine.com/games/blocks-that-matter/) looks nice, for example. I still don't understand the intention of this post: Wakfu shows that you can... make games in Java? Using premade sprites and tiles is usually simpler (using them, not creating the sprites) than it looks.